# I am trying to force IE to render/open a .js file in a text format in the webpage itself

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to force IE to render/open a .js file in a text format in the webpage itself. I am accessing the file which is external. I don't have any control over the code of the webpage/website. Chrome, Firefox & Safari can do so easily without any prompt. IE 8,9 & 10 on the other hand keeps asking me to download IE9.js instead of rendering the file. For example the link, http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js

I have tried every setting possible and I have looked into MIME Types but nothing is helping me. Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try handling the MIME types as outlined here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View-source) the built-in feature is no longer supported, so possibly read the file one line at a time and use `document.write`?

Comment: I wont be able to write any code because its an external website I am using. I pretty much want to be able to render any .js file directly in IE without it prompting for a download.

Comment: @admdrew I tried that and it didn't work for me.